# conflict with jdmenu, positionBy and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, conflicting-libraries

I am using [jdmenu plugin](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/1.4.1/) and it requires to include another 2 files jquery.dimensions.js and jquery.positionBy.js when I do that all the rest of my jquery plugins get out of position, for example autocomplete now displays on top:0 left:0, also dialog get on the same position.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Another thought, Jquery carry with its own position engine, right? Why jdmenu use its own files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is quite old, but I ran into this problem myself and determined it to be related to your thought about jQuery core's position utility.  I'm using jdMenu 1.4.1 with jQuery 1.7.1.  jdMenu used the original external Dimensions plugin, as it was originally written when jQuery 1.2.1 was the production release.  [As of jQuery 1.2.6](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2.6), the Dimensions plugin was moved into core.  In my case, the positioning problems went away as soon as I dropped the link to jquery.dimensions.js.